# Unexpected output from map reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have the following map and reduce functions that should give me the max date from a group.

Map:

```
function () {
    if (this.topic_id != 0) {
        emit(this.topic_id, {date_posted : this.date_posted});
    } 
}
```

Reduce:

```
function (key, values) {
    var re_date = ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z');
    values.forEach(function (value) {
        if (re_date == ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')) {
            re_date = value.date_posted;
        }
        if (re_date < value.date_posted) {
            re_date = value.date_posted;
        }
    });
    return {date_posted: re_date};
}
```

At the moment, it is giving the following output:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "value" : ISODate("2010-06-01T13:36:30Z") }
{ "_id" : "10", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-05-19T21:33:16Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1000", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-04T04:09:43Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1004", "value" : ISODate("2010-07-05T01:27:53Z") }
{ "_id" : "1007", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-04T23:44:56Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1009", "value" : ISODate("2010-08-12T19:05:35Z") }
{ "_id" : "1012", "value" : ISODate("2010-08-14T19:56:35Z") }
{ "_id" : "1014", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-05T07:18:56Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1022", "value" : ISODate("2010-07-06T21:17:57Z") }
{ "_id" : "1024", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-06T12:37:28Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1028", "value" : ISODate("2010-07-08T00:24:59Z") }
{ "_id" : "1029", "value" : ISODate("2010-07-26T12:08:34Z") }
{ "_id" : "1042", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-10-01T19:22:29Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1043", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-20T01:38:44Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1048", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-08T19:29:14Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1049", "value" : ISODate("2010-07-08T11:07:30Z") }
{ "_id" : "105", "value" : ISODate("2010-05-21T01:53:20Z") }
{ "_id" : "1053", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-08T17:53:57Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1056", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-08T22:35:02Z") } }
{ "_id" : "1060", "value" : { "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-09T06:33:57Z") } }
```

I was expecting that the value field for every line would always have the "date_posted" element but clearly only some have this. Do I have a mistake in my map function?

A sample of the original data:

```
db.posts.find({"topic_id" : {$in : ["105", "1053", "1000", "1004", "1007"]}}, {"date_posted" : 1, "topic_id" : 1})

{ "_id" : "1010", "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-05T01:27:53Z"), "topic_id" : "1004" }
{ "_id" : "106", "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-05-21T01:52:59Z"), "topic_id" : "105" }
{ "_id" : "107", "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-05-21T01:53:20Z"), "topic_id" : "105" }
{ "_id" : "1001", "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-04T04:09:43Z"), "topic_id" : "1000" }
{ "_id" : "1006", "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-04T23:21:30Z"), "topic_id" : "1004" }
{ "_id" : "1008", "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-04T23:44:56Z"), "topic_id" : "1007" }
{ "_id" : "1054", "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-07-08T17:53:57Z"), "topic_id" : "1053" }
```

Comment: Is it possible that the *value* of date_posted for some of your map inputs is something like `{ "date_posted" : ISODate("2010-10-01T19:22:29Z") }`?

Comment: is this the same issue you had in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742986/php-mongodb-map-reduce-db-assertion-failure ?

Comment: @ChrisShain But how will MR even execute successfully with some data as dates and some as strings?

Comment: WHat do the source documents look like for the ones that don't have "date_posted" as an array?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky no, but it is a follow up question. I corrected my code as you suggested in that post, but now I have this issue

Comment: @Sammaye I have posted a sample of the source documents. It looks like if the count is 1 it outputs as an array, but if it is > 1, it outputs as single value. I don't understand why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like my logic for getting the max date is screwed up. I had posted a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742986/php-mongodb-map-reduce-db-assertion-failure/11749702#11749702) for a related issue and the code posted by William Z in response to that question works better:

```
function (key, values) {
var re_date = ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z');
values.forEach(function (val) {
if ( re_date < val.date_posted ) 
re_date = val.date_posted;
}
);
return {date_posted : re_date}; }
```